# Bash - complex if condition statement, combining && and || to test arithmetic and string together

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, operators, brackets

I am trying to test few things together. but my if statement is throwing an error saying:

```
./script1.sh: line 30: expected `)'
./script1.sh: line 30: syntax error near `0)'
./script1.sh: line 30: `  if [[ (($1 < 0) || ("$1" == "-0")) && ($3 >= 0) ]]'
```

my actual code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sub(){      
if [[ (($1 < 0) || ("$1" == "-0")) && ($3 >= 0) ]]
then
 echo "Condition is true"
else
  echo "Condition is false"
fi
}
A=-0
B=50
C=-0
D=55
sub "$A" "$B" "$C" "$D"
```

can anyone suggest how to fix such issue?

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: I did that @Jetchisel, and that helped to remove some warnings. but still logically result is false.

Comment: `if (( $1 <= 0 && $3 > 0 )); then ...; else ...; fi` Just guessing here...

Comment: If you update your code, update the error you get as well. The new code iwith `-lt` s *not* going to produce an error message involving `<`.

Comment: Though really, you should not update the question in a way that invalidates an existing answer. If the syntax error has been resolved, accept the answer that fixed it and open a new question (with an [mcve]) for your next issue.

Comment: @chepner I will make a note of that for future.

Comment: I fixed it @chephner. please see new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493210/false-positive-if-condition-in-bash-testing-a-b-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, the following should work:

```
if [[ (($1 -lt 0) || ("$1" == "-0")) && ($3 -ge 0) ]]; then
    # Do something
else
    # Do something
fi
```

Are you sure you're running this with bash? Not all older shells support `[[`.

Comment: A non-`bash` shell is more likely. The difference between `<` and `-lt` wouldn't account for a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, that is showing no error now. But logical If condition is not working as expected.

Comment: @chepner yes I'm 99% sure that the wrong shell is being used.

Comment: @JPatel no-one can fix "not working as expected" without more detail

Comment: I just updated my code, please have a look. now you will be able to see the condition is still true while I am expecting it to be false with assigned values of A,B,C,D.

Comment: I am using it on ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @JPatel, with the arguments you provided: `((0 -lt 0) || ("-0" == "-0")) && (0 -ge 0)`, which is true? Not sure why you'd expect false...

Comment: I have provided C as -0 as well, which is false.

Comment: `-0` and `0` are the same thing in bash.

Comment: For the syntax error, I think the question is resolved I am creating new question for the false if condition.

Comment: and even if I test it with regex, it is still showing me false result. please see new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493210/false-positive-if-condition-in-bash-testing-a-b-c