# False positive IF condition, in BASH. Testing ((A ||B ) && C)

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, brackets, false-positive

Please see below example test code that I am getting false positive for:

```
#!/bin/bash
sub1(){      
if [[ (($1 -lt 0) || "$1" == "-0") && ($3 =~ re) ]]
then
 echo "Sub1: Condition is true $1 $2 $3 $4"
else
 echo "Sub1: Condition is false $1 $2 $3 $4"
fi
}

sub2(){      
if [[ (($1 -lt 0) || ("$1" == "-0")) && ($3 -ge 0) ]]
then
 echo "Sub2: Condition is true $1 $2 $3 $4"
else
 echo "Sub2: Condition is false $1 $2 $3 $4"
fi
}

nz='^-0$'
re='^[1-9]+$'
ne='^-[1-9]+$'
A=-0
B=50
C=-0
D=55
sub1 "$A" "$B" "$C" "$D"
sub2 "$A" "$B" "$C" "$D"
```

I am trying to pass multiple values of C (ex. 0, -0, 1, -1 etc)
Function Sub1 I am trying to check conditions using regex.
Function Sub2 I am trying to check conditions using arithmetic and string conditions.
None of them gives error but both provides false positive when you test with all possible values of C.

Any idea what's wrong in If statement?

Comment: `($3 =~ re)` -- missing `$` for `re` variable

Comment: Other than that, you'll have to show various cases of input and output and point out where the false positives are.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman , that was the issue. I tested and it works fine now. however I couldn't get why Sub2 is not working like that?

Comment: Please be more specific when you say "not working." `sub2` is true for `A=-0` and `C=-0`, do you think it should be false and if so why?

Comment: `-0 -eq 0` is true in bash, so `sub2` should be true